# Dynamically changing the click method in knockout JS

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using knockout templates to display certain HTML in the DOM. My scenario is such that, I re-use the template every time I want a div similar to the div in the template. However, each of these dynamically created divs will have buttons with different methods for click. The name of this method would be passed through the data attribute of the template:

```
<div class="module-container" data-bind="template: { name:'create-template', data:'abc' }">
</div>
```

and the template looks like this:

```
<tmeplate id="create-template">
   <button class="pagebuttons" data-bind="click: $data"></button>
<!-- More code here -->
</template>
```

So ideally, abc has to be called when the button is clicked but that's not happening (its literally considering $data as the method name. I tried escaping the $ sign and that didn't work too). How can I achieve this with Knockout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be passing a reference to the abc function. Not an 'abc' string.

Comment: Is there any special attribute that I can use to pass a reference? Also, how would I consume it in the click attribute?

Comment: You're not showing where the abc function is located. Is it a property on the view model?

Comment: @CrimsonChris That's a good question ! abc function is loaded using require JS and is a define module in another file (named abc). How would I pull a function defined using the define module and put it into knockout's click?

Comment: You would `require` the function and then add it as a property on your template's view model. `vm.myClick = myRequiredFunction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a context (a viewmodel) to the template as its `data` parameter. The bindings inside the template are based on that context.

```js
var vm = {};
vm.myClick = function() {
  alert("Clicked!");
};
vm.myLabel = 'Click me';

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<template id="create-template">
  <button class="pagebuttons" data-bind="click: theClick, text:label"></button>
  <!-- More code here -->
</template>
<div class="module-container" data-bind="template: { name:'create-template', data:{theClick:myClick, label:myLabel} }">
</div>
```

Comment: I have an issue now. one of the abc function is loaded using require JS and is a define module in another file (named abc). How would I pull a function defined using the define module and put it into knockout's click?

Comment: You would need to require that module when building your viewmodel, and make the function a member. If you need more detailed instructions, you'll need to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

From the knockout documentation(http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) something along this line is what you want:

```
<button data-bind="click: function(data, event) { myFunction('param1', 'param2', data, event) }">
  Click me
</button>
```

In your case, you are sending along the method name to invoke. Assuming this method is available on your root view model you could do the following:

```
<template id="create-template">
   <button class="pagebuttons" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent[data](data, event) }"></button>
    <!-- More code here -->
</template>
```

PS, $data is a reserved variable used by knockout to give you access to the entirety of the binding context. Avoid using the name 'data' entirely.